# Magento $order->addItem and getAllItems

Tags: magento

I try to add new order item to existed order (`$order`)

```
$orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item');
       $orderItem->setData($itemData);
       $orderItem->setOrder($order);
       $orderItem->save();
```

After that row with order item showes in database correctly, but when i do

```
var_dump($order->getAllItems());
```

i have `NULL`
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try reloading the order object after you added the new item:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order->getId());
var_dump($order->getAllItems());
```

Comment: Yes, the problem is, that you (Kate) didn't add the item to the order. $order->addItem($orderItem); then you can remove the $orderItem->setOrder, because this is done in the method.

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot about reloading my order.